# strange screen disturbance

Tags: screen

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and chrom as web server. I get often the strange dusturbance in some parts / lines on the screen like in the picture for example. Does anyone know why is this happening and how to fix it?

[image]

**EDIT**

Output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep SNA`:

```
[     5.087] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[     5.087] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[     5.114] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Broadwell (gen8) backend
```

Comment: What graphics card(s) do you have?  And have you tried installing any drivers?

Comment: This is the output of `sudo update-pciids`: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)`. I don't think i have tried to install any drivers recently.

Comment: can you post the output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep SNA` ?

Comment: i have posted it in my question

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Intel Graphics"
        Driver "intel"
        Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection
```

to this file : **/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

Comment: What do these lines do? I don't have the `xorg.config` file, should i create it myself?

Comment: Yes, if it's not there, create it.

Comment: I did it, but the problem still exists!

Comment: What is the ouput of `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel` ?

Comment: `xserver-xorg-video-intel:
  Installed: 2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`